# Code to Display Responsive HTML5 Animated Banner With Flash Fallback

Tags: html, css, dynamic, banner

HI and thanks for reading my first post.

I am a web developer in the UK and want to find a solution to display elements across a web page in a dynamic and responsive fashion.

**THE PROBLEM**

1) Html5 does not work properly in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

2) Flash does not work on all devices (due to *web compliance* restrictions - Thanks Apple! lol)

3) Responsive templates and elements are a necessity for different screen sizes.

**OBJECTIVE**

A) I want to achieve the same movie/banner built in HTML5 and Flash so that if the banner does not display correctly, it will fall back to a flash alternative (or the other way round - I would be interested to hear which is best in your opinion).

B) The banner needs to be responsive in both Html5 (as in adobe animate) and Flash (as in the flash output of Adobe Flash Pro CS6)

C) The banner needs to be able to be embedded in a page and display with the correct aspect ratio so the elements are displayed correctly - ie: the size of the animation elements and the position of those elements needs to be scaled as the screen size is changed.

**SOLUTION (So Far!)**

So far I have got to the stage of being able to produce the same animation in flash and html 5 using javascript, so that isn't a problem.

I thought to embed the banner as an iFrame - but then thought a chromeframe with a self install option for IE 9,8,7 etc would be better.

Then the iframe has to display the banner with a fallback to flash. so the code:

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="embed-container">
    <iframe src="http://mywebadress.com/banner.html" frameborder="0" seamless>
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object data="http://mywebadress.com/banner.swf" 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%">
        <param name=allowscriptaccess VALUE="always">
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </iframe>
  </div>
```

The animation is on a page http://mywebadress.com/banner.html and is using javascript to tween the animation. The frameborder=0 and seamless gets rid of the scroll bar, and all aditional properties are set by the CSS:

```
.banner {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.embed-container {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}   

.embed-container iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The most important thing to note is the padding-bottom: 56.25%; this will give the container its aspect ratio.
This is calculated as 9/16 = 0.5625 (for youtube for example) meaning that the height of the container is 56.25% the size of the width.

However I have only managed to get one example of the code working and I am unsure of what went wrong in future instances.

Any thoughts of development of this code would be great - I would live to hear your opinions on where I have gone wrong, or revisions and improvements!

Thanks :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd practice graceful degradation. If you always try to keep old IE6 working exactly the same as a modern browser, you're not going to enjoy web development very much. If the animation isn't required for the function of your site, then I'd just make it static.

Comment: Static is not the idea. Thanks for the comment but not very helpful, I think. I am looking to develop an animated banner element with tweening, interactive and dynamic responses. If I was talking about embedding a picture however I shall come to you! XD